# Deciding n_features value for scikit learn FeatureHasher

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-extraction

I have a categorical column with 4000 unique levels.

When using `sklearn.feature_extraction.FeatureHasher` for encoding , that column
What should be the n_features value to avoid collision.?

Answer (score 0):

`n_features` should be as large as possible to avoid collisions. is it possible for you to count all the unique values across all 4000 levels? if yes, you can set `n_features` to this value. setting `n_features` to a very large value may occupy a lot of RAM. Generally n_features between 2^28 to 2^32 is good enough

Comment: When researching FeatureHasher  we were looking at it to reduce the dimension of the encoded table generated . correct me if am wrong if i had to use 4000 as a n_features i would be better of using oneHotEncoding ?

Comment: "is it possible for you to count all the unique values across all 4000 levels" ..  - i did not understand this . - the actual size of the data set is 7,00,000 where a categorical column has 4000 unique values !

Comment: sorry, i dont understand this either.